# Image Uploading There are Several Approaches. When to choose one over others?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, image-upload

Currently I'm working with image uploading using MVC3. When I did some searches for sample code I found out several approaches. I figured out almost 3 methods. Can someone explain which one is better over the other or all of them are the same? An explanation when it comes to performance or anything is welcome.

**Method 1: As parameter**

```
public ActionResult UploadImage(HttpPostedFileBase img)
        {

            return View();
        }
```

**Method 2: From Request.Files**

```
HttpPostedFileBase imgFile= Request.Files["img"];
```

**Method 3: From Image Helper**

```
var imgFile= WebImage.GetImageFromRequest();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first is the best approach. The reason for that is because this will make the action easier to unit test and it doesn't rely on magic strings.